# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AND' in python html

Tags: sql, sql-server, python-2.7, syntax, odbc

I am running the code in Spyder(python2.7), the code create a user interface. I put all the values it needed in the input box but it return me with an error message

> "('42000', u"[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL
>   Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AND'. (156)
>   (SQLExecDirectW)")"

This is what it should be like:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.vw_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
WHERE ProbabilityofClosing= xx AND InvestmentProgram = 'xxxxxInvestments'
  AND MostLikelyAmount = 55555 AND MostLikelyFundingDate = '06112019'
  AND CashOutflowOrInflow = 'Cash Outflow'
  AND (FundingCurrency = 'CAD' OR FundingCurrency = 'CLP' OR
       FundingCurrency = 'COP' OR FundingCurrency = 'CNH')
```

but it shows this:

> DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'SELECT * FROM
>   dbo.vw_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  WHERE InvestmentProgram = ' xxxxxx' AND  AND
>   AND CashOutflowOrInflow = 'Cash Outflow' AND FundingCurrency = 'BRL'
>   AND DealStatus = 'Funded'': ('42000', u"[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL
>   Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AND'.
>   (156) (SQLExecDirectW)"

Comment: What is the code that generates this query? The expressions in your WHERE clause are not being created correctly. (See the `AND AND AND` part)

Comment: the code produce this:

Comment: def inputBox(text, inputid, inputtype = 'text'):
    return html.Div([                
            html.Div(dcc.Checklist(id = inputid+'-check', options=[{'value': inputid}]),style={'display': 'inline-block'}),     
            html.Div(children = text, style={'display': 'inline-block', 'height': '45px', 'left':'30px'}),
            html.Div(dcc.Input(id= inputid, type=inputtype), style={'display': 'inline-block', 'position':'absolute', 'left': '200px', 'height': '45px', 'width':'200px'})
                 ])

Comment: emmmmmmmmmm. .... this is mot all of it, the code is every long how can I post it?

Comment: I would guess that the query is being generated dynamically.  The code says something like:   append "AND";   if we need to filter on MostLikelyAmount then append "MostLikelyAmount=5555";   append "AND";   and so on.    If this clause does not appear then you end up with consecutive AND's.